# How to unzip and unrar a file from terminal?

Tags: unzip, rar

I would like to know what are the commands line used to unzip and unrar a file from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

cd into the directory which contains the file and

type this command in the terminal :

```
tar -xvf filename.gz
```